# access to database without a need for Authorized networks in cloud sql

Tags: java, mysql, google-cloud-platform

i made a java application that anybody can use it from different location, i want to every user to have the access to the database in the cloud sql , my question is how can i access to the database  without a need for Authorized networks

Answer (score 2):

Security Warning: Do not allow the Internet to access Cloud SQL.

Your question states **without a need for Authorized networks**. If that is a requirement, then you must implement a server to proxy requests for Cloud SQL. That server will need to use the Cloud SQL Auth Proxy or have access via private IP.

[About the Cloud SQL Auth proxy](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)

To allow public Internet access, use the address range **0.0.0.0/0**. This means adding that value as an authorized network.

[Authorizing with authorized networks](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks)

You can also use the CLI:

```
gcloud sql instances patch INSTANCE --authorized-networks=0.0.0.0/0
```

[gcloud sql instances patch](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/instances/patch#--authorized-networks)